# How do you deal with NULL values while creating JsonObject?

Tags: java, json

I am learning Java and JSR-353. My question is quite forward.
Having the method below:

```
public JsonObject createJsonObject() {
    return Json.createObjectBuilder()
            .add("address", this.getAddress())
            .add("city", this.getCity())
            .add("state", this.getState())
            .add("postalcode", this.getPostalcode())
            .add("country", this.getCountry())
            .add("contactNumber", this.getContactNumber())
            .add("secondContactNumber",this.getSecondContactNumber())
            .build();
}
```

How do you deal if any of the attributes is NULL?

Comment: Um, the same way you deal with any other null value?  What do you mean specifically by "how do you deal?"

Comment: @RobertHarvey one may guess that the question is about how to switch between add and [addNull](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObjectBuilder.html#addNull-java.lang.String-) depending on whether value is null or not (add would throw NPE if null). But it's unclear if this is the question or something else

Comment: Maybe you could subclass/wrap the builder, and add null checks in .add() that redirect to .addNull() if needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a JSON "object" (aka dictionary), there are two ways to represent absent values: Either have no key/value pair at all, or have a key with the JSON value null.

So you either use .add with a proper value what will get translated to null when you build the JSON, or you don't have the .add call.

Comment: but what if you want to merge and overwrite an existing value?

Comment: Don’t merge JSON. Change your model objects, then create new JSON. If you MUST change JSON, then you either delete the existing key or add a key with a null value.

Answer (score 1):

It is a JSON-B design deficiency. They could have done something slick like:

```
Json.createObjectBuilder().addIfNotNull("address", this.getAddress());

Json.createObjectBuilder().add("address", this.getAddress(), defaultOnNull);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to handle `null`, but this requires an explicit check, what beats the purpose, if you ask me. You can do this, thou:

```java
String value;
// ...
return Json.createObjectBuilder()
    .add("my-key", value != null ? Json.createValue(value) : JsonValue.NULL)
    .build();
```

If you hoped for `Json.createValue(String)` to accept `null` strings, then you'll be disappointed as well.

Answer (score -1):

I fixed this "feature" and created this project https://github.com/leonardofel/JSON-java-put-null-fix

making the following code bellow possible:

```
    String v = null;
    JSONObject j = new JSONObject().put("myPreciousNull", v);
    System.out.println(j.toString());
```

prints:

```
    {"myPreciousNull":null}
```

just works !!!